# Soap data gives Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Tags: php, api, soap

I am retriveing data from a soap api using php. but unable to get the data in a array. Every time it gives me error

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in**

> stdClass Object   (
>
> ```
> [item] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [date] => 2008-07-17T01:23:06Z
>                 [directory] => 1
>                 [downloadCount] => 0
>                 [downloadLink] => http://www.example.com/folder/8ISxjbEs/_online.html
>                 [empty] => 
>                 [id] => 8290268
>                 [md5] => 
>                 [name] => 
>                 [parentId] => -1
>                 [removed] => 
>                 [shared] => 
>                 [size] => 17
>                 [version] => 0
>             )
>
>         [1] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [date] => 2009-11-03T23:03:15Z
>                 [directory] => 
>                 [downloadCount] => 5
>                 [downloadLink] => http://www.example.com/file/mIofv-vJ/MASTER-ACCOUNTS_3_Nov_2009.html
>                 [empty] => 
>                 [id] => 146103085
>                 [md5] => b073b9573227843e25d19e0e9e60ce80
>                 [name] => MASTER-ACCOUNTS 3 Nov 2009.zip
>                 [parentId] => 8290268
>                 [removed] => 
>                 [shared] => 
>                 [size] => 3401447
>                 [version] => 0
>             )
>   ) )
> ```

Ok i am using 4shared API.

//User credentials on 4shared

```
$user_login = "email_123@hotmail.com";
$user_password = "password";

$client = new SoapClient("https://api.4shared.com/jax2/DesktopApp?wsdl", array(
"cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_DISK,
"trace" => 1, 
"exceptions" => 0
)
); 

$client->yourFunction();
//Getting list of all folders 
echo "<pre>";

$getAllItems  = $client->getAllItems ($user_login, $user_password);

print_r  ($getAllItems);
```

this code is printing the above stdClass object. but i am unable to convert it into array.

Comment: Please post the code used to retrieve and store the SOAP response.

Comment: I have added more detail please check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried converting using the get_object_vars(); function?

```
<?php

function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}

?>
```

*I know it's kinda late to answer but i came across this question while looking for a solution for my problem so here's my 2 cents :)

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to cast that object as an Array:

```
class myClass {
...
}
$myobj = new myClass();
$myArrObj = (Array) $myobj;
```

Or you can try to iterate through this object and push all elements to an new array using [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)